# Flexbox Grid Container

Tags: html, css, grid, flexbox

While trying out flexboxgrid out of the box for the first time in my chrome v46 1366 resolution a sample menu I created appears to be stacked vertically rather than horizontally as a flex layout should be. When you tryout the code in a jsfiddle however, it appears to be okay. I believe it has something to do with the container width? How should i fix it?

Here's the [fiddle:](https://jsfiddle.net/cov3hn8b/)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row center-xs middle-xs">
        <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-4">
             <h1><a href="#">My Logo</a></h1>

        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-12">
            <nav>
                <ul class="row">
                    <li class="col-xs"><a href="#">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="col-xs"><a href="#">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="col-xs"><a href="#">Menu</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="col-xs"><a href="#">News</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="col-xs"><a href="#">Photo</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--end of .row-->
     <h2>A flexible menu based on the 
  <a href="http://flexboxgrid.com/" target="_blank">Flexbox Grid</a> framework.
</h2>

    <p class="p">Demo by George Martsoukos. <a href="http://www.sitepoint.com/3-modern-tools-using-flexbox-grids" target="_blank">See article</a>.</p>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    /*            display: flex;*/
    /*            flex-direction: column;*/
    background: #4c493e;
    color: white;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
h1, ul, li {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
li {
    list-style: none;
}
a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.p {
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    padding-top: 150px;
    font-size: .9em;
}
.p a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
/* LOGO STYLES
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
h1 {
    margin-left: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 24px;
    background: #ffee91;
}
h1 a {
    display: block;
}
/* MENU STYLES
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
div.row {
    min-height: 80px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    margin: 0;
}
.col-xs {
    padding: 0;
    border-right: solid 1px #444;
}
nav {
    margin-right: 5px;
}
ul a {
    display: block;
    padding: 15px 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background: #fff0a0;
    transition: background .3s ease;
}
ul a:before {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    padding-right: 5px;
    font-size: 22px;
    display: inline-block;
}
ul li:nth-child(1) a:before {
    content:'\f015';
}
ul li:nth-child(2) a:before {
    content:'\f0eb';
}
ul li:nth-child(3) a:before {
    content:'\f115';
}
ul li:nth-child(4) a:before {
    content:'\f1ea';
}
ul li:nth-child(5) a:before {
    content:'\f03e';
}
ul a:hover {
    background: white;
}
/* SECOND LINE STYLES
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
h2 {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
}
h2 a {
    padding: 5px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #FEB41C;
    transition: all .3s ease;
    color: white;
}
h2 a:hover {
    background: #FEB41C;
    color: black;
}
/* MQ STYLES
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
@media screen and (max-width: 876px) {
    nav {
        margin: 0 5px;
    }
    div.row {
        height: auto;
    }
    h1 {
        font-size: 18px;
    }
    h1, ul {
        margin: 20px 0;
    }
    ul a {
        font-size: 0;
    }
    ul a:before {
        padding: 0 5px;
        font-size: 32px;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    ul a:before {
        font-size: 22px;
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1600px) {
    .col-sm-offset-2 {
        margin-left: 16.666%;
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1600px) {
    .col-sm-offset-2 {
        margin-left: 16.666%;
    }
}
```

Here's the image from my browser: [image: flexbox menu]

Comment: Please post the link to the jsfiddle! :)

Comment: Sorry. Posted both the jsfiddle and my browser screen :)

Comment: The problem is bootstrap.

Comment: What do you mean? It doesn't use bootstrap. Its a standalone grid. If that waht you meant?

Comment: Are you using boostrap in your project?

Comment: No. Just the grid. Check out flexboxgrid.com It has a similar syntax of bootstrap media querries.

Comment: Oh sorry, i thought you are using bootstrap and that its conflicting with flexbox grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the flexboxgrid stylesheet link in your primary document, but not the fiddle demo.

Add this to your HTML doc in the `<head>` section:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/flexboxgrid/6.3.0/flexboxgrid.min.css">
```

It's already in the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cov3hn8b/) (see "External Resources").